# What happens when you complete Mario Party Superstars achievements?

Tags: mario-party-superstars

There are currently few articles about the completion of Mario Party Superstars, and all of them seem to be incomplete when it comes to the achievements. Although it is known that the game does not provide any unlockable characters and boards, I wondered what the achievements would maybe unlock. So, do you get anything from completing an achievement group (constellation) or even all of them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, not much. You don't unlock anything special from the completion of the achievements (nor the small groups of achievements). You do get the titles associated with each achievement though, which are the following:

---

**- OFFLINE -**

***Mountain achievements:***

- **Team Player**: Win without letting your opponents win a single game *(Tag Match)*.
- **Continuous Winner**: Clear selected stage *(Trio Challenge)*.
- **Peak Performer**: Clear selected stage with an S rank *(Trio Challenge)*.
- **Coin-Collecting Champ**: Win and collect 50 or more coins during a playthrough *(Coin Battle)*.
- **Golden Touch**: Win and collect 100 or more coins during a playthrough *(Coin Battle)*.
- **Block Star Pro**: Reach level 50 in Block Star *(Sports and Puzzles)*.
- **Block Star Boss**: Reach level 99 in Block Star *(Sports and Puzzle)*.
- **Stick and Spin Pro**: Reach level 50 in Stick and Spin *(Sports and Puzzles)*.
- **Stick and Spin Boss**: Reach level 99 in Stick and Spin *(Sports and Puzzles)*.
- **Puzzle Party Pro**: Get 300 points in Mario’s Puzzle Party *(Sports and Puzzles)*.
- **Puzzle Party Boss**: Get 600 points in Mario’s Puzzle Party *(Sports and Puzzles)*.

***Coin achievements:***

- **Star Collector**: Get 3 or more Stars during an adventure *(Mario Party Mode)*.
- **Celestial Compiler**: Get 5 or more Stars during an adventure *(Mario Party Mode)*.
- **Coin Collector**: Get 100 or more Coins during an adventure *(Mario Party Mode)*.
- **Coin Enthusiast**: Get 150 or more Coins during an adventure *(Mario Party Mode)*.
- **Coin Tycoon**: Get 200 or more Coins during an adventure *(Mario Party Mode)*.
- **Coin Thief**: Steal 30 Coins from rivals during an adventure *(Mario Party Mode)*.
- **Persistent Pickpocket**: Steal 50 Coins from rivals during an adventure *(Mario Party Mode)*.
- **Star Thief**: Steal 1 Star from a rival during an adventure *(Mario Party Mode)*.
- **Celestial Swindler**: Steal 3 Stars from a rival during an adventure *(Mario Party Mode)*.
- **Coin Finder**: Find Coins in a Hidden Block *(Mario Party Mode)*.
- **Starlit Destiny**: Find a Star in a Hidden Block *(Mario Party Mode)*.

***Pipe achievements:***

- **Troublemaker**: Land on an Event Space 30 times *(Mario Party Mode)*.
- **Risk-Taker**: Land on a Chance Time Space 15 times *(Mario Party Mode)*.
- **Challenge Seeker**: Land on a VS Space 15 times *(Mario Party Mode)*.
- **Rainmaker**: Land on a Koopa Bank 15 times *(Mario Party Mode)*.
- **Bowser's BFF**: Land on a Bowser Space 15 times *(Mario Party Mode)*.
- **Generous Donor**: Deposit coins into the Koopa Bank 50 times *(Mario Party Mode)*.
- **Greedy Gardener**: Plant a strawberry and have it steal a Star in Peach’s Birthday Cake *(Mario Party Mode)*.
- **Space Fugitive**: Get chased by a runaway spaceship 3 times during an adventure in Space Land *(Mario Party Mode)*.
- **Bringer of Night**: Switch day to night at the Mystery Mansion in Horror Land *(Mario Party Mode)*.
- **Bountiful Harvest**: Take at least 3 fruit during an adventure in Woody Woods *(Mario Party Mode)*.
- **Cheep Chomp Trainer**: Switch Toadette and Bowser’s places during an adventure in Yoshi’s Tropical Island *(Mario Party Mode)*.

***Dice block achievements:***

- **Doubles Champ**: Roll doubles when using the Double Dice *(Mario Party Mode)*.
- **Treasure Hunter**: Use a special item *(Mario Party Mode).
- **Always Ready**: Use an item 8 times during an adventure *(Mario Party Mode)*.
- **Conquered the King**: Win a Bowser minigame *(Mario Party Mode)*.
- **Bonus Hoarder**: Get all bonus Stars during an adventure *(Mario Party Mode)*.
- **Treasured Friend**: Keep a Skeleton Key till the adventure ends *(Mario Party Mode)*.
- **The One to Beat**: Be nominated to win during the homestretch *(Mario Party Mode)*.
- **Minigame Fan**: In one game, win in half of all minigames *(Mario Party Mode)*.
- **Star Doubler**: Get 2 Stars in one turn *(Mario Party Mode)*.
- **Deadly Duelist**: Win a duel *(Mario Party Mode)*.
- **Empty Pockets**: Miss getting a Star due to insufficient of Coins *(Mario Party Mode)*.
- **Bargain Shopper**: Get a Star for half the usual price *(Mario Party Mode)*.

***Star achievements:***

- **Galaxy Builder**: Get 7 or more Stars during an adventure *(Mario Party Mode)*.
- **Minigame Pro**: In one game, win all minigames *(Mario Party Mode)*.
- **Minigame Master**: Win a total of 100 minigames.
- **Coin Master**: Collect a total of 1,000 coins.
- **Super Star**: Play Mario Party mode 50 times *(Mario Party Mode)*.

---

**- ONLINE -**

***Crown achievements:***

- **A-Rank Master**: Earn a skill grade of A in a minigame *(Sports and Puzzles)*.
- **S-Rank Legend**: Earn a skill grade of S in a minigame *(Sports and Puzzles)*.
- **Crowd Pleaser**: Receive applause 1,000 times *(Mario Party Mode)*.
- **Making Friends of Foes**: Receive applause 5,000 times *(Mario Party Mode)*.
- **Made the Ranks!**: Earn 50,000th place or higher in a single minigame.
- **Diligent Gamer**: Earn 10,000th place or higher in a single minigame.
- **Top-Tier Gamer**: Earn 1,000th place or higher in a single minigame.
- **Good Learner**: Get 3 Stars in a single pack *(Daily Challenge)*.
- **5-Streak Master**: Win 5 times in a row *(Survival)*.
- **10-Streak Champion**: Win 10 times in a row *(Survival)*.
- **Puzzle Party Boss**: Get 600 points in Mario’s Puzzle Party *(Sports and Puzzles)*.

---

On top of that, each group has its own cute background once completed:

**Offline achievements background:**

> [image: Offline achievements background]

**Cute fireworks on offline completion:**

> [image: Offline achievements completion fireworks]

**Online achievements background:**

> [image: Online achievements background]